# CVE mapping to Java library

Tags: java, maven, security, owasp

There is [dependency-check-maven](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html) plugin which checks if 3rd party dependencies in my Java project have known vulnerability. The issue is that this plugin has lot of false positives (and quite likely false negatives) due to the fact that CVE does not contain unique identifier of the library. For example recent Spring vulnerability [CVE-2018-1275](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-1275) contains identifier `cpe:2.3:a:pivotal_software:spring_framework:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:* versions from (including) 4.3.0 up to (excluding) 4.3.16` which is quite hard to map to exact Maven dependency. See this [article](https://www.veracode.com/blog/managing-appsec/using-cpes-open-source-vulnerabilities-think-again) for more details.

Is there is some openly accessible mapping between CVEs and Maven dependencies that would allow more reliable check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 other options I know of. In alphabetical order:

- https://github.com/OSSIndex/ossindex-maven-plugin
- https://github.com/snyk/snyk-maven-plugin

Answer (score 2):

There is now another option which is [open source vulnerabilities(osv)](https://osv.dev/) and the dataset that backs this including many vulnerabilities including Maven and the exact matches are [available publicly](https://github.com/google/osv.dev). This eliminates the need to translate via cpe's instead the CVE is just linked directly to the maven package using format of Maven.

Comment: Finally, a decent solution. Been a long time coming for the Java community.